# Foreign inheritance subject to U.S. taxes for permanent resident?

Tags: united-states, taxes, foreign-income, taiwan

My wife is a permanent legal resident (I am a U.S. Citizen), is the money brought into the United States in the form of an inheritance subject to taxes? Her mother recently passed away in Taiwan and we want to transfer the inheritance money back to the U.S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

US Federal Income Tax is not imposed on inheritances, and I suspect (though am not fully sure) that most States don't impose State Income Tax on inheritances (California and Taxachussetts might be notable exceptions). *Estate taxes* (if any) are paid by the estate before the inheritances are doled out, and so that is not an issue either. Just be sure to have all the paperwork in Taiwan properly sorted out so that your wife has proof that the money was in fact an inheritance. If she inherited stocks and bonds, you should consult a lawyer to determine whether she gets a step-up in basis or not for those items.

Comment: Also, depending on the amount, don't take advice from strangers on the internet and ask a CPA/Lawyer about the implications. (I'm reasonably sure this answer is correct, but it doesn't hurt to be safe)